# Echo Multidimensional json and php

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to accessing an API that has json input with multi dimensional, this is the array

```
[{
"Value 1":"a",
"Value 2":
    {
        "Value 3":
        {
            "Value4":11,
            "Value5":"C",
        },
        "Value 4":
        {
            "Value6":12,
        }
    }
}]
```

I want to echo the "11" in Value4 and "12" in Value6. I've try to echo it

```
$varkota = 'url to json output';
$datakota = json_decode(file_get_contents($varkota, true));
$data1 = json_decode($datakota[0]->Value2);
$data2 = json_decode($data1[0]->Value3);
echo $data2[0]->Value4;
```

error told me:

```
 ! ) SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in debug.php on line 6
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0020  145280  {main}( )   ..\debug.php:0
2   4.1329  188648  json_decode ( ) ..\debug.php:6

( ! ) SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in debug.php on line 7
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0020  145280  {main}( )   ..\debug.php:0

( ! ) SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in on line 8
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0020  145280  {main}( )   ..\debug.php:0
```

Any idea?

Comment: I can't validate your json string `Error: Parse error on line 6:
...   "Value5": "C",  },  "Value 4": {  
----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', got '}'`

Comment: @RohanKumar edited

Comment: @YudhistiraBayu there is error in json.   "Value5":"C",  comma is not allowed at last key.

Comment: @YudhistiraBayu your json is not valid(check on http://jsonlint.com) try my updated answer and demo with valid json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you need to use `json_decode` only once, and your keys are having spaces and the keys which are having spaces then you need to enclose it as string and in `{}`. Try it like,

```
$datakota = json_decode(file_get_contents($varkota, true));
$data1 = $datakota[0]->{'Value 2'};
$data2 = $data1->{'Value 3'}; // no need to use array [0], as Value 2 is object
echo $data2->Value4; // no need to use array [0], as Value 3 is also an object
```

In a single line, just use it as

```
echo $datakota[0]->{'Value 2'}->{'Value 3'}->Value4;
```

**[Online Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3b3208ebdf282c963711de4bf11027d36c65bb4a)**

Answer (score 1):

You just have to call `json_decode` one time.

```
$varkota = 'url to json output';
$datakota = json_decode(file_get_contents($varkota, true));
$data1 = $datakota[0]->Temperature->Metric;
// ...
```

Or with your current json string

```
$data1 = $datakota[0]->{"Value 2"}->{"Value 3"};
```

Comment: I see no benefit for the question opener, but I added an alternative for the changed structure..